# Invalid timestamp error when trying to get CSV file from and S3 bucket using boto3 module in python2.7

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get a .csv file stored in an S3 bucket. The CSV is being uploaded by a Mac compiler to the S3 bucket and my code (python 2.7) is running in a Unix environment. CSV looks like this (I have included carriage return character):

```
Order,Item,Date,Quantity\r
1,34975,8/4/15,10\r
2,921644,3/10/15,2\r
3,N18DAJ,1/7/15,10\r
4,20816,12/12/15,9\r
```

My code to get the file from the s3 bucket:

```
import boto3

def readcsvFromS3(bucket_name, key):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=bucket_name, key=key)
    response = obj.get()
    data = response['Body'].read()
```

Error is happening on the `response = obj.get()` line. And the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slot.py", line 163, in <module>
    columnNames, rowArray = neo.readcsvFromS3(bucket_name=config.s3bucket, key=config.orde
  File "/home/jcgarciaram/WMSight/wmsight-api/api/utilities/pythonScripts/slotting/neo4jUt
    response = obj.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 481, in d
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __c
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 228, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 481, in _make_api
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 117, in make_re
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 144, in _send_r
    request, operation_model, attempts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 203, in _get_re
    parser.parse(response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 208, in parse
    parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 570, in _do_pars
    member_shapes, final_parsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 626, in _parse_n
    member_shape, headers[header_name])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 226, in _parse_s
    return handler(shape, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 149, in _get_tex
    return func(self, shape, text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 380, in _handle_
    return self._timestamp_parser(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 344, in parse_time
    raise ValueError('Invalid timestamp "%s": %s' % (value, e))
ValueError: Invalid timestamp "Wed, 16 Jan 48199 20:37:02 GMT": year is out of range
```

I have been researching all over but can't seem to figure out the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: what does `date` command in terminal returns?

Comment: date commands returns expected value of: Tue Mar 29 09:06:50 EDT 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching and debugging we were able to finally determine the cause of the issue. We tried uploading the files in a JSON format rather than CSV format and imagine our surprise when we saw the same error when trying to download the file using boto3 in Python.

We started looking then at the properties of the files themselves in S3 (right-click on file and click on Properties) rather than the content.

We found a section called Metadata and found the following entry:

```
Key: Expires / Value: Tue, 15 Jan 48199 02:16:52 GMT.
```

After changing the year of the value to a date such as 2200, everything worked fine! We are now looking into our upload process in Node.js to see how we can make sure that this value is set correctly.